# Querying Google Play Music and Fetching playlists

Tags: android, playlist, android-contentresolver

It seems there are some changes from Android side and not documented. I had tough time figuring out how to fetch playlists in Android.

This is the code which finally worked :

```
    String[] playListProjection = { MediaStore.Audio.Playlists._ID,
            "playlist_name" };
    Uri uri = Uri
            .parse("content://com.google.android.music.MusicContent/playlists");
    cursor = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().query(uri,
            playListProjection, null, null, null)
```

Now as a part of 2nd Activity I want to fetch the playlist by name and Android is throwing error :

Here is the code :

```
    cursor = ((Activity) context).getContentResolver().query(Uri.parse("content://com.google.android.music.MusicContent/playlists"),
            projection,
            "playlist_name = ?",
            new String[] {name},
            null);
```

Here is the error I am getting :

```
07-03 20:08:55.051: E/DatabaseUtils(14062): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Selection is not supported. 'playlist_name = ?' is ignored
```

I have 2 queries :

1. Is there a better way to fetch playlists in Android ?
2. Any idea how to resolve this error which I am getting ?

Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know of a way to get around this. You're using an unsupported ContentProvider URI anyway, and the documentation online for it has proven to be sparse. If that Provider doesn't support selection then it doesn't support selection.

Try querying "content://com.google.android.music.MusicContent/audio" and seeing the column names there. That's what I'm doing.